# What math should I learn to get in depth with Elliptic Curve Cryptography research?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, elliptic-curve-generation

My background is computer scientist. I have done applied cryptography research for a while. Currently, I'm working on Elliptic curve cryptography.

To understand the *idea* and how to use Elliptic curve cryptography (ECC) is not that complicated. I understand basic algebra, [EC point addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication), [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field), [Discrete Logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), etc.

However, When it comes to **improving** ECC research, it requires a lot of mathematical knowledge. For instance, if I want to **introduce a new curve** (like when Bernstein, Birkner, Joye, Lange, and Peters introduced Twisted Edwards curve in 2008) and evaluate its security, or **trying to solve** Elliptic Curve Discrete Log Problem (**ECDLP**), **what math field(s) should I study?**

Comment: Elliptic curves can arguably be regarded as a "math field" in their own right; many books have been devoted to them (starting more or less with the seminal book of Silverman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[An Introduction to the Theory of Elliptic Curves](https://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/Presentations/WyomingEllipticCurve.pdf) (Brown University)

[Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography) (Wikipedia)

[Performance analysis of identity management in the Session Initiation Protocol](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4493606&isnumber=4493499) (SIP) (IEEE)

[Overview of Elliptic Curve Cryptosystems](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2013). (RSA.com)

[Lecture by Dan Boneh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WDOpzxpnTE) (Youtube)